# Norm square of an integral

Tags: integration, normed-spaces

Is it allowable to do like this:

$$
\Psi(x,t) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{k^2/a}*e^{ikx}*e^{-ik^2t}
$$
$$
|\Psi(x,t)|^2 = |\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{k^2/a}*e^{-ikx}*e^{-ik^2t}dk|^2
$$
$$
|\Psi(x,t)|^2 = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |e^{k^2/a}|^2*|e^{-ikx}|^2*|e^{-ik^2t}|^2dk
$$

$$
|\Psi(x,t)|^2 = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |e^{k^2/a}|^2*1*1dk
$$
where $|e^i|^2 = e^i*(e^i)^{*}=1$

If not then why?

Comment: It is *not*. In general, $|a+b|^2\neq|a|^2+|b|^2$.

Comment: To expand on @OlivierOloa's comment, when equality holds, $a$ and $b$ are said to be orthogonal.

Comment: @OlivierOloa, thanks. Maybe you can post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not.

In general, for $a_i \in \mathbb{C}$, we have
$$
|a_1+a_1+\cdots+a_n|^2\neq|a_1|^2+|a_2|^2+\cdots+|a_n|^2.
$$